# Is this a valid variable name?

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program or function that

- checks if a variable name is valid and
- output `1` or `True` if it is valid,
- `0.5` if it is valid but starts with an underscore (`_`),
- and `0` or `False` if it is not valid.

### Rules

- A variable name in most languages is valid if it begins with an underscore or letter (a – z, A – Z, _) and the rest of the characters are either underscores, letters, or numbers. (a – z, A – Z, 0 – 9, _)
- Output `1` or `True` if the variable name is valid and `0` or `False` if not valid.
- However, it is not good practice to start a variable with an underscore, so return `0.5` if it starts with an underscore and the name is valid.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

### Test Cases

| input | output | reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `abcdefghijklmnop` | `1` |  |
| `_test_` | `0.5` | starts with an underscore |
| `123abc` | `0` | starts with a number |
| `A_b1C_23` | `1` |  |
| `_!` | `0` | not `0.5` because it’s not valid |
| `magical pony1` | `0` | no spaces |

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.
**Bonus:** −10% if your program/function outputs `0` for an empty string(`""`).

Comment: can we output `true`/`false`/`0.5`?

Comment: Can we output truthy/falsy/anything?

Comment: You can output `true/false/0.5`

Comment: Just noting, in python, under scores are often used.  Classes need an __init__ function, helper functions in classes are sometimes begun with an underscore.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk beware of mini-markdown; you meant `__init__`; also, no, classes do not *need* an `__init__` but typically have one

Comment: Can we assume that the input will be non-empty? (Most of the current answers seem to fail for empty input.)

Comment: -2% for accounting for an empty input.

Comment: Does that bonus round up or down? If up, it's really not worth having for the current set of answers

Comment: @muddyfish Why would the bonus round at all?

Comment: -10% now, and don't round. Express your answer as a decimal.

Comment: shouldn't a single underscore return 0?

Comment: No, it should return `0.5`. In languages like JavaScript, you can define a variable called `_`.

Comment: I see, you're right!

Comment: May we assume the input is entirely made of digits, plain Latin letters, underbars, and spaces?

Comment: MATLAB has a built-in function to check for valid variable names that conform to exactly the same rules as seen here (except for the 0.5 for the beginning underscore).  Are built-in functions allowed?

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ No, the fitfh test case contains an exclamation mark, so I don't think so.

Comment: Several current answers incorrectly give `1` for non-ASCII input, like `Ψ`.

Comment: May we assume the input is entirely made of ASCII (≤127)? (Ping @AandN)

Comment: If you do, you must say so in your answer.

Answer (score 13):

### JavaScript (ES6), 37 - 10% = 33.3 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @edc65

Saved 5.6 bytes thanks to @Mateon

```
s=>!/^\d|\W|^$/.test(s)/-~(s[0]=='_')
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is not perl?

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

Code:

```
¬D'_Qsa·+¹žj-""Q*2/
```

Explanation:

```
¬                     # Push input and also push the first character.
 D                    # Duplicate the first character.
  '_Q                 # Check if it is equal to an underscore character.
     sa               # Swap and check the duplicate if it's an alphabetic character.
       ·              # Double the value.
        +             # Add both values up
         ¹            # Take the first input.
          žj-         # žj is short for [a-zA-Z0-9_]. This will be substracted from the
                        initial string. 
             ""Q      # Check if the string is empty.
                *     # Multiply this with the first value.
                 2/   # Halve it, resulting into 0.0, 0.5, or 1.0.
```

In short, the formula for the string `s` in pseudocode is:

```
((s[0] == '_' + s.isalpha() × 2) × (s.remove([a-zA-Z0-9_]) == "")) / 2
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqxEJ19Rc2HCtyvCucW-ai0iIlEqMi8&input=bWFnaWNhbCBwb255MQ)

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 6):

### PHP (50 - 10% = 45)

Thanks to Schism for the -2 :)

```
preg_match('/^[a-z_]\w*$/i',$s)?$s[0]=='_'?.5:1:0;
```

Not to compete with the golflang answers, but I thought I'd try it anyways.

```
preg_match('/^[a-z_]\w*$/i', $s) # Matches every a-zA-Z0-9_ string that doesnt start with a number
?   $s[0] == '_'                   # Then, if it starts with an _
    ?   .5                         # give 0.5 points
    :   1                          # If it doesn't, give 1
:   0;                             # If it didn't match the regex, give 0
```

Something to note is that in PHP, without the `/u` modifier, `\w` only selects ASCII letters. In some other languages/Regex flavours, this pattern won't work.

**Edit**: I see a lot of people using \w and \d in their answers, when they use a language that includes non-ASCII letters and digits too. That is NOT the puzzle. They are wrong. (Can't downvote/comment yet, sorry to need to tell it this way.)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. This is a great answer; often [tag:code-golf] challenges are within languages as well as between them. I'm giving you a +1 for this solution! Well done.

Comment: You can shave off two characters with `[a-z].../i`.

Comment: @Schism Thank you. Don't know how I managed to forget that, usually I'm good at these kind of regex puzzles :)

Comment: About your edit: can you be more specific - what languages? In javascript `\d` is exactly the same as `[0-9]`. `\w` is exactlly the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: The code page that the language uses is irrelevant; as long as the regex properly handles ASCII, it's valid. All of the current regex-based answers work, to my knowledge. You're not trying to match a variable name in your language; rather, you're trying to match a variable name based on the rules in the challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## Retina, <s>30 - 10% = 27</s> <s>28 - 10% = 25.2</s> 29 - 10% = 26.1 bytes

Both versions qualify for bonus, as they handle empty input correctly (outputs `0`)

I had to fix a bug caused by one of .NET regex features, which considers some (read as many) Unicode characters as "word" characters. Fortunately, this cost me only a single byte in both versions. It only came down to adding a modifier to make the regex matching behavior compliant to ECMAScript standards. More about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_5).

#### New <s>28</s> 29-byte version, made by @MartinBüttner. Thanks!

```
^_
$_¶_
Mme`^(?!\d)\w+$
2
0.5
```

#### Explanation

First, we check if the input starts with an underscore. If it does, the input is duplicated, with a newline in between. For example: `_test_` -> `_test_\n_test_`, where `\n` is the newline. Then we try to match anything, that doesn't start with a number, but is followed by any number of "word" characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, digits, and underscore) *on each line*. Note that if input started with an underscore and was replaced to two lines, this will match both lines. Then we check if we had 2 matches, and replace them with `0.5`. Empty or invalid line will always yield 0 matches, and valid variable names always yield 1 match.

---

#### My own <s>30</s> 31-byte version

```
Ae`^\d|\W
^_.*
0.5
^\D.*
1
^$
0
```

#### Explanation

First of all, we check if input starts with a digit or contains a non-word character (anything other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, digits and underscore). If it does, it's discarded, because it's invalid. Then we check if it starts with an underscore. If it does, it's replaced with `0.5`. Then we check if it starts with a non-digit character (at this point the first character is either `0`, `a-z`, or `A-Z`. Only `a-z` and `A-Z` are non-digits, obviously). If it does, it's replaced with a `1`. Then we check for empty string and replace it with `0`.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Xl8KJF_Ctl8KTW1lYF4oPyFcZClcdyskCjIKMC41&input=X3Rlc3Rf)
[Try it online! Old version](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=QWVgXlxkfFxXCl5fLioKMC41Cl5cRC4qCjEKXiQKMA&input=X3Rlc3Rf)

Comment: Waitwaitwait. At the `^\D.*` stage it can start with a 0? That's weird.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy It can, if it started with a `_` and was replaced with `0.5`. Then it starts with a 0.

Comment: This incorrectly gives a 1 for input `Ψ`.

Comment: @TimmyD Interesting. I don't understand why does it do so. Quick check indicates that `\w` is matching non-ASCII characters, which it shouldn't do (I've tried to give it `ƜƝƞƟƠ` and `ᎳᎴᎵᎶᎷᎸᎹ` as input). I'll look into this later. Possible solution seems replacing `\w` with `[a-zA-Z\d_]`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 36 bytes

```
lambda s:s.isidentifier()/-~(s[:1]=='_')
```

The code is **40 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-10% bonus**.

Note that this will only work correctly for code pages that don't have non-ASCII letters/digits.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 27 bytes

```
1)95=2/8M3Y2m+G7M95h4Y2hmA*
```

This works in [current version(15.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/15.0.0) of the language.

Input is a string with single quotes.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MSk5NT0yLzhNM1kybStHN005NWg0WTJobUEq&input=J190ZXN0Xyc)

#### Explanation

```
1)      % take input implicitly. Get its first element
95=     % true if it equals 95 (underscore)
2/      % divide by 2: gives 0.5 if underscore, 0 if not
8M      % push first element of input again
3Y2     % predefined literal: string with all letters
m       % true if it's a letter
+       % add. Gives 1 if letter, 0.5 if underscore
G       % push input again
7M      % push string with all letters again
95h     % concatenate underscore
4Y2h    % predefined literal: string with all digits. Concatenate
mA      % true if all input chars belong to that concatenated string
*       % multiply. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 21 bytes

#### (noncompeting, added string subtraction, various string constants)

```
Qh~u{Q~J\_+-|!Qh\_qh/
```

Explanation:

```
Qh~u{                 - Check first char isn't a digit
     Q~J\_+-          - Is the input alphanumeric + "_"
            |!        - Combine
              Qh\_q   - Is the first char an "_"
                   h/ - Combine
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, 27 bytes

```
c!|-rz0++G\_JjkUT}hzJhqhz\_
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=c!|-rz0%2B%2BG%5C_JjkUT%7DhzJhqhz%5C_&input=abcdefghijklmnop%0A123abc%0A_test_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=abcdefghijklmnop%0AABcdefghijklmnop%0A123abc%0A_test_&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gogh](https://github.com/zachgates7/Gogh), 29 bytes

```
÷"[^\W\d]\w*"g¦"_.*"g+÷2=0.5¿
```

Run using:

```
$ ./gogh no '÷"[^\W\d]\w*"g¦"_.*"g+÷2=0.5¿' "_test"
```

---

#### Explanation

```
                   “ Implicit input                               ”
÷                  “ Duplicate the TOS                            ”
"[^\W\d]\w*"g      “ Fully match the STOS against the TOS (regex) ”
¦                  “ Swap the STOS and TOS                        ”
"_.*"g             “ Fully match the STOS against the TOS (regex) ”
+                  “ Add the TOS to the STOS                      ”
÷                  “ Duplicate the TOS                            ”
2=                 “ Determine if the TOS is equal to 2           ”
0.5¿               “ Leave the correct output on the stack        ”
                   “ Implicit output                              ”
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 21 bytes

```
$_=!/\W|^\d//2**/^_/
```

The score includes **+1 byte** for the `-p` switch. Try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/7JreBb).

Comment: could you have, say `-$_||$_=...` to account for the empty answer? (using `-` because `+` is a noop in perl)

Comment: No, that's a runtime error. But even if it worked, it would make my score worse.

Comment: I only did minimalistic tests, so I'll trust you. Fair that 10% of 21 bytes isn't much..

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
c!:z"\W|^\d"0h!xz\_
```

Try it with the [Pyth Compiler](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=c%21%3Az%22%5CW%7C%5E%5Cd%220h%21xz%5C_&input=abcdefghijklmnop%0A123abc%0A_test_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=abcdefghijklmnop%0A_test_%0A123abc%0AA_b1C_23%0A_%21%0Amagical+pony1&debug=0).

Note that this will only work correctly for code pages that don't have non-ASCII letters/digits.

#### How it works

```
c!:z"\W|^\d"0h!xz\_  (implicit) Save the input in z.

  :z        0        Test if z matches the following regex:
    "\W|^\d"           A non-word character or a digit at the beginning.
                     This returns True iff z is an invalid name.
 !                   Apply logical NOT to yield True iff z is a valid name.
               xz\_  Find the first index of the underscore in z.
                     This yields 0 iff z begins with an underscore.
             h!      Apply logical NOT and increment.
                     This yields 2 if z begins with an underscore, 1 otherwise.
c                    Divide the two results.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 19 bytes - 10% = 17.1

```
{(0≤⎕NC⍵)÷1+'_'=⊃⍵}
```

`{`…`⍵`…`}` anonymous function where the right argument is represented by `⍵`
`⊃⍵` first character (gives space if empty)
`'_'=` 1 if equal to 'underbar, 0 otherwise
`1+` evaluates to 2 if initial underbar, 1 otherwise
`⎕NC⍵` [name class](http://help.dyalog.com/14.1/Content/Language/System%20Functions/nc.htm); -1 if invalid name, 0 if undefined (but valid name), 2-9 if defined (and thus valid)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org/), 84 * 0.9 = 76.5

```
USE: regexp
[ R/ [_a-zA-Z]\w*/ R/ _.*/ [ matches? 1 0 ? ] bi-curry@ bi 0 = 1 2 ? / ]
```

Runs on the listener (repl), defines a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a string and outputs { 0 | 1/2 | 1 }.

Defining it as a word it's 97 chars:

```
USE: regexp
: v ( s -- n ) R/ [_a-zA-Z]\w*/ R/ _.*/ [ matches? 1 0 ? ] bi-curry@ bi 0 = 1 2 ? / ;
```

#### How does it work:

`R/ [_a-zA-Z]\w*/ R/ _.*/` defines two regular expressions. `bi-curry@` partially applies the quotation `[ matches? 1 0 ? ]` to each regex, leaving two curried quotations on the stack. `bi` applies each quotation to the argument string.

Each of those (curried quotations) leave either a 1 or a 0, depending if they matched. The first matches on the well formed names, the second on names starting with underscore.

`0 = 1 2 ? /` The last value is replaced with a 1 if it was 0, or with a 2 if it was 1. Then the first (1 or 0, valid or not) is divided by the second (2 or 1, starts with underscore or not).

This is loooong! Any pointers to shrinking a bit more appreciated...

And I hate regexps!

#### PS.

```
{ 0 } [ "" v ] unit-test
{ 0 } [ "" v ] unit-test
{ 0 } [ "1" v ] unit-test
{ 0 } [ "1var" v ] unit-test
{ 0 } [ "var$" v ] unit-test
{ 0 } [ "foo var" v ] unit-test
{ 1 } [ "v" v ] unit-test
{ 1 } [ "var" v ] unit-test
{ 1 } [ "var_i_able" v ] unit-test
{ 1 } [ "v4r14bl3" v ] unit-test
{ 1/2 } [ "_" v ] unit-test
{ 1/2 } [ "_v" v ] unit-test
{ 1/2 } [ "_var" v ] unit-test
{ 1/2 } [ "_var_i_able" v ] unit-test
{ 1/2 } [ "_v4r14bl3" v ] unit-test
```

all test pass ;)

Comment: Just wondering, is the whitespace truly necessary? I can't say for sure since I don't know the language or have the interpreter.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll yeah, not the best golfing language! In the Forth tradition, only delimiter are whitespace chars.

Comment: Oh, I see. Here, have an upvote.

Comment: Yay, ty! Now to break havoc with my comment-everywhere priv!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 34 + 1 = 35 bytes

```
$_=/^([^\W\d])\w*$//(($1 eq"_")+1)
```

Uses the `-p` flag.

### Explanation

```
$_=/^([^\W\d])\w*$//(($1 eq"_")+1)
   /^([^\W\d])\w*$/                 matches any string that starts with an underscore or a letter of the alphabet followed by 0 or more alphanumeric + underscore characters. The first character is stored in a capture group
                   /                divide result by
                    (($1 eq"_")+1)  (capture == "_") + 1. This is 1 if the first character was not an underscore and 2 if it was.
$_=                                 assign to $_ and implicitly print
```

Comment: `[_a-zA-Z]` -> `[^\W\d]` if perl works the same as JavaScript, I think you'd also have to do `\w*`

Comment: @Downgoat Seems to work fine with `\w+`.

Comment: matches false for `a`

Comment: @Downgoat Ah, right. I see.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 93 bytes

```
If[#~StringMatchQ~RegularExpression@"[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z_]*",If[#~StringTake~1=="_",.5,1],0]&
```

I'm honestly not sure if this *can* be golfed further.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 84 -10% = 76 bytes

```
lambda x:[0,[[.5,1][x[0]>'z'],0][x[0]<'A']][x.replace('_','a').isalnum()]if x else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 22 bytes

```
hkdc¬:[kr\_+?F¬?h\_=ß½
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=hkdc%C2%AC%3A%5Bkr%5C_%2B%3FF%C2%AC%3Fh%5C_%3D%C3%9F%C2%BD&inputs=_test_&header=&footer=)

A mess.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Guess which genius once upon a time suggested removing `_` from Japt's `\w` character class thereby costing himself 3 bytes here! ETH *was* going to add a new class with `_` included but then he disappeared.

```
¥f"[%l_][%w_]+")/ÒUè"^_
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pWYiWyVsX11bJXdfXSsiKS/SVegiXl8&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3Ai) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pWYiWyVsX11bJXdfXSsiKS/SVegiXl8&input=WwoiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcCIKIl90ZXN0XyIKIjEyM2FiYyIKIkFfYjFDXzIzIgoiXyEiCiJtYWdpY2FsIHBvbnkxIgpdLW1S)

Comment: japt forking time?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES7, 37 bytes

```
x=>!x.match(/\W|^\d/)/2**/^_/.test(x)
```

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3Dx%3D%3E!x.match(%2F%5CW%7C%5E%5Cd%2F)%2F2**%2F%5E_%2F.test(x)%3B%0A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22abcdefghijklmnop%22%2C%201%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22_test_%22%2C%20.5%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22123abc%22%2C%200%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22A_b1C_23%22%2C%201%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22_!%22%2C%200%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22magical%20pony1%22%2C%200%5D%0A%5D.map(x%3D%3E%60%27%24%7Bx%5B0%5D%7D%27%20%3D%20%24%7Bf(x%5B0%5D)%7D%2C%20expected%20%24%7Bx%5B1%5D%7D%60).join(%60%0A%60))

How it works:

```
x=>                                   // Fat arrow function
   !x.match(/\W|^\d/)                 // Gives false if contains non word or starting 
                                      //   with a digit. Booleans in numeric context will 
                                      //   be 0 or 1
                      2**             // 2 to the power of...
                         /^_/.test(x) // gives true if starting with '_'. 
                                      //   true -> 1 -> 2**1 -> 2
                                      //   false -> 0 -> 2**0 -> 1
                     /                // Devide the lValue boolean with the numeric rValue:
                                      // lValue = 0 or 1
                                      // rValue = 2 or 1
```

Port of @Dennis's Perl answer

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 57 - 10% = 51.3 bytes

```
->(s){case s
when'',/^\d/,/\W/
0
when/^_/
0.5
else
1
end}
```

A pretty naïve approach

Comment: 51.3 bytes, mind you. :)

Comment: @Xesau whoops - embarassing. Fixed now :)

Comment: You save a huge amount of bytes if you use ternary chaining: `->(s){s=~/^$|^\d|\W/?0:s=~/^_/?0.5:1}`

Comment: @KevinLau True - I added [another ruby answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75847/46678) in that vein already (though it's not great either)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 44 bytes

```
->(s){s=~/^(_|\d)?\w*$/?$1?$1==?_?0.5:0:1:0}
```

Comment: You don't need parens around the parameters for stabby lambdas

Comment: Also if you can figure out a way to drop that extra ternary you can probably save some bytes.  Maybe `/^([a-z_]).../i` instead of `/^(_|\d)?.../`

Comment: @NotthatCharles D'oh... you're right. I'll give it a closer look when I a chance

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 82 - 10% = 73.8

```
v=function(s)return(s:match("^[_%a]+[_%w]*$")and 1or 0)*(s:match("_")and.5or 1)end
```

Test Cases:

```
print(v("a") == 1) -- true
print(v("1") == 0) -- true
print(v("_") == 0.5) -- true
print(v("") == 0) -- true
print(v("1a") == 0) -- true
print(v("a1") == 1) -- true
print(v("_1") == 0.5) -- true
print(v("_a") == 0.5) -- true
print(v("1_") == 0) -- true
print(v("a_") == 0.5) -- true
```

Comment: I think you can use STDIN to eat at least 10 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 68 * .9 = 61.2 bytes

```
s=arg[1]print(s:find("^[%a_][%w_]*$")and(s:find("^_")and.5or 1)or 0)
```

Takes arguments on the command line

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.3](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>46</s></sup> 44 -10% = <sup><s>41.4</s></sup> 39.6 bytes

```julia
!s=[1 .5]count.(r"^[a-z]\w*$"i=>r"^_\w*$",s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6/TsMwEMZ3P4WbMiSoTUgrlqBUFMSCEAMdGEqJzo7ruDhOFF/6h4k35JGCE7VisP2777v7fLtWK4iP3ZhCnoucKkOfe4nG4ZyMaYFY2ySKpMKiZSGvymiwX8DIaNdTxHTFor1rD2@i16f3VVjmYyMOU61YA81pum0NR1UZSx7AChfRGvRrQBSNSZI3IcVxQi02ysgkWTJHwHE11He02otGQ51uQVsRpFoYiYXPK60FR18AL0pAXlzyLkH/g@c3CIJuZNN1TMPbzbBC6Dfe5xqm35uPw/WVp9KFq7OBJzboUFi0NKVr4nnEA8ZzsZWF2n3p0lS1k7K@I3MQz@bOdrDMWPyYzea9OXJXCVJx0LSuzCnuRXd@fzyyIeQ@pLXbE7Xxzx8t6GigoPsD)

#### explanation

- `r"^[a-z]\w*$"i` is the regex for a variable not starting with a `_` (the `i` means case-insensitive)
- `r"^_\w*$"` for a variable starting with a `_`
- `count.()` counts the number of time each regex appears in s, result is in a vector (similar to a 2×1 matrix)
- `[1 .5]` is a 1×2 matrix, when multiplied by the previous result, gives the expected result (0.5 when starting with `_`, 1 otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZDBTsJAEIbjlacYGhJ3IzQUQmJISkKAgwcuGk-ozVKWsthum91FJJQn8YIHvfhEevBZnHaBRA7NdL5_5t-ZefvUIYtZ-2viNGS6Zko6jz8Xv-l0yUMDYyYkbCsAMz6HBBPCVKS70FeKbSZ3RgkZPdIu3EthwC8rAV5YDIZrM2Caa6RjlpFSAHDYNESraCGWz3Ei08yBRg-8-lEOir6ghE23c8Jeq42NFp9gP5h6g6DVPreontUlLBK4ImSp3HhWKyVaKcNpUneeKs7CBWwhxByIkNnK1IG_ZngKPqPg9w6exYaK61VcLI2JmDHD7TVsFz0UZohMLIl2bgrchdrBdHQwRXL0r8NtaYnIetdhkCqFGpLt8Tn_NM_Osa_sKsVXsVP9H6YLBIj9pX5vmK6mMcc14GNl5o3r73vt98ScaFfoUZKZTZ5r0qSYDUUkTJ5DVbsJM-GCa-I8PTysr2oOpW4TeIz3KTqx3Pcvg0vqdiz03KY1f9_ZuN_b-Ac)

```scala
s=>if(s.isEmpty||s(0).isDigit|| !s.matches("^\\w+$")).0 else if(s(0)=='_').5 else 1.0
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZLNboJAEMeTHn2KkZgIKZKiMWlMNDHqoQcvbXqqLVlggbV8lV3aGsuT9OKlfag-TYddIMYDWeY3M_-dj_3-5R6JyeR0-ilFMLr9u3rL3D31BGwJS-HYA_BpAAkaOilCPoNlUZDD04MoWBo-GzN4TJmAuYwEeCcxCMrFinDKkW5JrksHgEZcD6XCiO1f4yTNcg1GC7DN1u3UeY6EN9a0w_Z4gokKd3DpuPbKGU8uJfoXcQkJGbYHeZYebOWTLqMnj65SK8gKSrwIjuChDTpL81KYQD9zHAX1DZgvGs26w4LyMq6bRoP5RFA1DZVlNIE5IhGnOtfuajyDQSO6aUSRtPom3EtJRErbhFVWFOhDcmyvm3f1VJq6perVX7Oji2JwVeoPd7TOSjem3ZZYoHOL8U2SiwN8fQG3Ikp8JGsW4jKR9LmVEOFFlOvay273cT3QDKPJBtyPGmMFNMZpSblaoS5x6AzPA6fngS2223xZfqVeXvMA24f4Dw)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val testCases = Map(
      "abcdefghijklmnop" -> 1,
      "_test_" -> 0.5,
      "123abc" -> 0,
      "A_b1C_23" -> 1,
      "_!" -> 0,
      "magical pony1" -> 0
    )

    testCases.foreach { case (input, expected) =>
      val result = validateString(input)
      println(s"Input: $input, Expected: $expected, Result: $result, Correct: ${result == expected}")
    }
  }

  def validateString(s: String): Double = {
    if(s.isEmpty || s.head.isDigit || !s.matches("^\\w+$")) {
      0.0
    } else if(s.head == '_') {
      0.5
    } else {
      1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), (22 + 1 `-p` bytes) * .9 = 20.7

```perl
$_=!/\W/*/^\D//2**/^_/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZRPyZcX0s/LsZFX99IC8iI1///nystPz8psYjLKbGCKz4zLa2SyznfP4fLwrI4MSUpMeVffkFJZn5e8X/dghwA)